# How do I pass commands serially without using pipe through telnet

Tags: linux, multithreading, command-line, automation

I am doing automation by sending commands through telnet serial port in command line. 
My question is, I have two telnet ports where I send commands in parallel to each one and copy the result to a text file.

But here is the thing! The commands I pass are in only one session, It's like I am passing the arguments one after another.

For example, I do each step in parallel and then do `cat c1` and `cat c2`:

```
In telnet 1                        telnet 2

#touch c1                          #touch c2
>cat c1                            >cat c2
```

Now after I run `cat c1` I  get some result in telnet 1 and when I run `cat c2`, then I get some more result added in c1 and not in c2. I have to copy the `cat c1` result to a text file and then run last commands in parallel:

```
>the                                >the
```

As you can see after I run `touch c1`, I don't get `#` but`>` which continues.

Can you tell me how to proceed in parallel?

I used a pipe but it didn't work as I don't get result from `cat c1` after `cat c2` is executed, but I get only `cat c1` result.

I may not have explained very clearly, but tried. if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Comment: It it unclear what you actually did and what happened vs. what you'd want to happen, also how you can _do each step in parallel_ _in only one session_.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are looking for asynchronous processing of commands. Asynchronous commands execute in parallel.

The command should be terminated with `'&'`, then the shell executes the command in background....

ex:

```
touch c1 & touch c2
```

Comment: It is something like concurrency testing